# Why is the click event triggered several times in my Backbone app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mouseevent, backbone-events

I'm making a Backbone.js app and it includes an index view and several subviews based on id. All of the views have been bound with mousedown and mouseup events. But every time I go from a subview to the index view and then go to any of subviews again, the mousedown and mouseup events in the current subview will be triggered one more time, which means when I click the subview, there will be several consecutive mousedown events triggered followed by several consecutive mouseup events triggered.

After looking through my code, I finally found that it's the router that causes this problem. Part of my code is as follows:

```
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "category/:id": "hashcategory"  
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this._categories = new CategoriesCollection();
        this._index = new CategoriesView({collection: this._categories});

    },

    index: function(){
        this._categories.fetch();
    },

    hashcategory: function(id){
        this._todos = new TodosCollection();
        this._subtodolist = new TodosView({ collection: this._todos, 
                                            id: id                                              
                                         });
        this._todos.fetch();
   }
```

As you can see, I create the index collection and view in the `initialize` method of the router, but I create the subview collection and view in the corresponding route function of the router. And I tried to put the index collection and view in the `index` function and the click event in index view will behave the same way as subviews. So I think that's why the mousedown and mouseup will be triggered several times.

But the problem is, I have to use the `id` as one of the parameters sent to subview. So I can't create subview in the `initialize` method. What's more, I've already seen someone else's projects based on Backbone and some of them also create sub collection and view in the corresponding route function, but their app runs perfectly. So I don't know what is the root of my problem. Could someone give me some idea on this?

Comment: What do the two views look like?

Comment: index view and all sub views all use the a same <div> element. Every time I use router to switch between these views, I just use `render()` to change the content of this <div> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're having a delegate problem because:

> all sub views all use the a same `<div>` element

Backbone views bind to events using jQuery's [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on their `el`. If you have a view using a `<div>` as its `el` and then you use that same `<div>` for another view by replacing the contained HTML, then you'll end up with both views attached to that `<div>` through two different `delegate` calls. If you swap views again, you'll have three views receiving events through three `delegate`s.

For example, suppose we have this HTML:

```
<div id="view-goes-here"></div>
```

and these views:

```
var V0 = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { 'click button': 'do_things' },
    render: function() { this.$el.html('<button>V0 Button</button>'); return this },
    do_things: function() { console.log('V0 clicked') }
});        
var V1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { 'click button': 'do_things' },
    render: function() { this.$el.html('<button>V1 Button</button>'); return this },
    do_things: function() { console.log(V1 clicked') }
});
```

and we switch between them with something like this (where `which` starts at 0 of course):

```
which = (which + 1) % 2;
var v = which == 0
      ? new V0({el: $('#view-goes-here') })
      : new V1({el: $('#view-goes-here') });
v.render();
```

Then you'll have the multi-delegate problem I described above and this behavior seems to match the symptoms you're describing.

Here's a demo to make it easy to see: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AtvWJ/

A quick and easy way around this problem is to call [`undelegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents) on the current view before rendering the new one:

```
which = (which + 1) % 2;
if(current)
    current.undelegateEvents(); // This detaches the `delegate` on #view-goes-here
current = which == 0
      ? new V0({el: $('#view-goes-here') })
      : new V1({el: $('#view-goes-here') });
current.render();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HazzN/

A better approach would be to give each view its own distinct `el` so that everything (including the `delegate` bindings) would go away when you replaced the HTML. You might end up with a lot of `<div><div>real stuff</div></div>` structures but that's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks, man! I have solved it with your method. I can't appreciate more!

Comment: @chaonextdoor: You're welcome. I've had similar problems that didn't become visible until it was too late to give each view its `el`, I ended up retrofitting the `undelegateEvents` hack. I think using separate `el`s is a cleaner approach though.